# How to make one class "eat" another?

Tags: python, eclipse, pygame, simulation, pydev

I currently have 3 classes. A class for grass, sheep and wolves. I would like to make it so that whenever a wolf and sheep are on the same x and y position the wolf would eat the sheep. I'm getting this error though...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\wolfAndSheepSimulation\simulationMain.py", 
line 82, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\wolfAndSheepSimulation\simulationMain.py", 
line 38, in main
w.update(grassList[w.x][w.y])
File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\wolfAndSheepSimulation\wolf.py", line 74, in 
update
self.wolfKill()
File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\wolfAndSheepSimulation\wolf.py", line 67, in 
wolfKill
for (self.x, self.y) in (s.Sheep.x, s.Sheep.y):
AttributeError: type object 'Sheep' has no attribute 'x'
```

Here is my code for the function wolfKill...

```
def wolfKill(self):
    for (self.x, self.y) in (s.Sheep.x, s.Sheep.y): #if they are both on the same x and y position then...
        Wolf.energy += s.Sheep.energy #adds the current energy level of the sheep to the wolves energy level
        s.Sheep.energy -= 15 #subtracts 15 from the energy which in turn kills the sheep
```

Here are the classes

```
import pygame as p
import random as r 
import variables as v
SQ_LENGTH = v.SQ_LENGTH
NUM_OF_SQUARES = v.NUM_OF_SQUARES

class Grass(object):
'''
class for creating grass
'''
MAX_GRASS_GRAZES = v.MAX_GRASS_GRAZES
GRASS_REFRESH_RATE = v.GRASS_REFRESH_RATE

def __init__(self, x, y):
    '''
    Parameters: x, y
    attributes: x, y, energy, color, turnsToRegrowth
    '''
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.energy = Grass.MAX_GRASS_GRAZES
    self.turnsToRegrowth = Grass.GRASS_REFRESH_RATE
    self.colors = [(79,69,37), (99,99,41), (104,119,41), (102,140,36), (89,155,27), (60,201,18)]

def draw(self, screen):


    p.draw.rect(screen, self.colors[self.energy], p.Rect(self.x * SQ_LENGTH, self.y * SQ_LENGTH, SQ_LENGTH, SQ_LENGTH))


def update(self):         
    '''
    If regrowth counter has counted to 0,
    then the grass regrows one energy unit.
    Otherwise, increment regrowth timer
    '''
    if self.turnsToRegrowth <= 0 and self.energy < Grass.MAX_GRASS_GRAZES:
        self.energy +=1
        self.turnsToRegrowth = Grass.GRASS_REFRESH_RATE
    else:
        self.turnsToRegrowth -=1

def graze(self):
    self.energy -= 1   

def decompose(self):
    self.energy = Grass.MAX_GRASS_GRAZES
```

Sheep

```
import random as r
import pygame as p
import variables as v

#global variables within the class
SQ_LENGTH = v.SQ_LENGTH
NUM_OF_SQUARES = v.NUM_OF_SQUARES
WIDTH = HEIGHT = SQ_LENGTH
RADIUS = SQ_LENGTH//2 #integer division

class Sheep(object):
'''
A class for creating sheep
'''

def __init__(self, x, y):
    '''
    Parameters: x, y
    Attributes: x, y, color
    '''
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.color = (255, 255, 255)
    self.energy = 15

def draw(self, screen):
    p.draw.circle(screen, self.color, ((self.x * WIDTH + WIDTH//2,
                                        self.y * HEIGHT + HEIGHT//2)), RADIUS)

def move(self):
    '''
    move a sheep one square randomly in one of four directions
    make sure sheep doesn't go off the screen
    '''
    direction = r.randint(0, 3)

    if direction == 0 and self.y < NUM_OF_SQUARES - 1:
        self.y += 1
    elif direction == 1 and self.y > 1:
        self.y -= 1
    elif direction == 2 and self.x > 1:
        self.x -= 1
    elif direction == 3 and self.x < NUM_OF_SQUARES - 1:
        self.x += 1

    self.energy -= 1

def isAlive(self):
    if self.energy > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def canGraze(self, grassSquare):
    if grassSquare.energy > 0:
        return True 
    else:
        return False

def graze(self, grassSquare):
    grassSquare.graze()
    self.energy +=1

def update(self, grassSquare):
    if self.isAlive():
        if self.canGraze(grassSquare):
            self.graze(grassSquare)
        else:
            self.move()
    else:
        grassSquare.decompose()
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)
```

Wolf

```
import random as r
import pygame as p
import variables as v
import sheep as s

#global variables within the class
SQ_LENGTH = v.SQ_LENGTH
NUM_OF_SQUARES = v.NUM_OF_SQUARES
WIDTH = HEIGHT = SQ_LENGTH
RADIUS = SQ_LENGTH//2 #integer division

class Wolf(object):
'''
A class for creating wolves
'''

def __init__(self, x, y):
    '''
    Parameters: x, y
    Attributes: x, y, color
    '''
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.color = (139, 150, 168)
    self.energy = 15

def draw(self, screen):
    p.draw.circle(screen, self.color, ((self.x * WIDTH + WIDTH//2,
                                        self.y * HEIGHT + HEIGHT//2)), RADIUS)

def move(self):
    '''    
    move a sheep one square randomly in one of four directions
    make sure sheep doesn't go off the screen
    '''
    direction = r.randint(0, 3)
    if direction == 0 and self.y < NUM_OF_SQUARES - 1:
        self.y += 1
    elif direction == 1 and self.y > 1:
        self.y -= 1
    elif direction == 2 and self.x > 1:
        self.x -= 1
    elif direction == 3 and self.x < NUM_OF_SQUARES - 1:
        self.x += 1

    self.energy -= 1

def isAlive(self):
    if self.energy > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def canHunt(self, sheepSquare):
    if sheepSquare.energy > 0:
        return True 
    else:
        return False

def wolfKill(self):
    for (self.x, self.y) in (s.Sheep.x, s.Sheep.y): #if they are both on the same x and y position then...
        Wolf.energy += s.Sheep.energy #adds the current energy level of the sheep to the wolves energy level
        s.Sheep.energy -= 15 #subtracts 15 from the energy which in turn kills the sheep

def update(self, sheepSquare):
    if self.isAlive():
        if self.canHunt(sheepSquare):
            self.wolfKill()
        else:
            self.move()
    else:
        sheepSquare.decompose()
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: We have no idea what your classes look like, so we can't be much help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please show us the classes

Comment: From the error message, you're clearly using the `Sheep` class instead of an instance of your `Sheep` class... among many other problems... I don't think you understand what `for` does, for example...

Comment: I added the classes

Comment: You'll have to code the `wolfkill` method again because there are problems with the way you are using the `for` loop. To get the wolf to eat the grass, you could add all grass objects to a `Group` and when the wolf collides with any object in the group, remove it. The code would look something like: `pygame.sprite.spritecollide(wolf, all_grass_sprites, True)`. The `True` parameter will tell pygame to remove any objects that are colliding with the wolf.

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to a class attribute. You can tell it by the traceback "AttributeError: type object 'Sheep' has no attribute 'x'". Each class in python has it's metaclass, the default metaclass is 'type', so "type object 'Sheep'" refers to the class Sheep. If you want to have access to another object, you should pass it as an argument to a method e.g. "def wolfkill(self, sheep)". To get an intuition about class attributes, try thinking of them as the ones that generally don't change, they describe the sheep in general, but tell you nothing about the individual sheep (which instance attributes are used for).
In order to solve your main problem (acting when a sheep meets a wolf), you might want to read about the Observer Pattern. I hope this helps, Good Luck!